# Converting .jpg images to .png

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've looked around and read the docs, and found no way or solution, so I ask here. Is there any packages available to use Python to convert a JPG image to a PNG image?

Comment: There appear to be python bindings to ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/.  I haven't used them, but I've used ImageMagick, and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could always use the [Python Image Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) for this purpose. There might be other packages/libraries too, but I've used this before to convert between formats.

This works with Python 2.7 under Windows ([Python Imaging Library 1.1.7 for Python 2.7](http://effbot.org/downloads/PIL-1.1.7.win32-py2.7.exe)), I'm using it with 2.7.1 and 2.7.2

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('Foto.jpg')
im.save('Foto.png')
```

Note your original question didn't mention the version of Python or the OS you are using. That may make a difference of course :)

Comment: Well, it says Python 2.7 is required, and I have 2.7.3 so it won't let me install. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1417933 if you are windows you need a flavour of PIL (32 or 64) compatible with your Python.

Comment: When i open the resultant image in IrfanView I get alert saying it's JPG image in png extension. Is result originally png?

Python 2.7 on 64 bit windows machine

Comment: PIL is dead. Use Pillow now. See here to install: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20061019/4561887

Comment: Note, however, that these instructions still work fine, as Pillow is a fork from PIL, and in this case the import and commands are identical.

Answer (score 13):

Python Image Library: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

From: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

```
import Image
im = Image.open("file.png")
im.save("file.jpg", "JPEG")
```

> save
>
> im.save(outfile, options...)
>
> im.save(outfile, format, options...)
>
> Saves the image under the given filename. If format is omitted, the
>   format is determined from the filename extension, if possible. This
>   method returns None.
>
> Keyword options can be used to provide additional instructions to the
>   writer. If a writer doesn't recognise an option, it is silently
>   ignored. The available options are described later in this handbook.
>
> You can use a file object instead of a filename. In this case, you
>   must always specify the format. The file object must implement the
>   seek, tell, and write methods, and be opened in binary mode.
>
> If the save fails, for some reason, the method will raise an exception
>   (usually an IOError exception). If this happens, the method may have
>   created the file, and may have written data to it. It's up to your
>   application to remove incomplete files, if necessary.

Answer (score 12):

As I searched for a **quick converter of files in a single directory**, I wanted to share this short snippet that converts any file in the current directory into .png or whatever target you specify.

```
from PIL import Image
from os import listdir
from os.path import splitext

target_directory = '.'
target = '.png'

for file in listdir(target_directory):
    filename, extension = splitext(file)
    try:
        if extension not in ['.py', target]:
            im = Image.open(filename + extension)
            im.save(filename + target)
    except OSError:
        print('Cannot convert %s' % file)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from glob import glob                                                           
import cv2 
pngs = glob('./*.png')

for j in pngs:
    img = cv2.imread(j)
    cv2.imwrite(j[:-3] + 'jpg', img)
```

this url: https://gist.github.com/qingswu/1a58c9d66dfc0a6aaac45528bbe01b82

Answer (score 1):

```py
import cv2

image =cv2.imread("test_image.jpg", 1)

cv2.imwrite("test_image.png", image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use python myself, but try looking into:
http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

```
import Image
im = Image.open("infile.png")
im.save("outfile.jpg")
```

(taken from http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-April/700256.html )