# how to replace jpg images with png images

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have Jpg images which are in one folder. I want to replace that images with png format in the same folder and same name.how to do this?
here what i tried:

```
image_path =''
input_image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
input_image.save(image_path + ".png", "PNG")
```

Comment: this has been discussed in the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759117/converting-jpg-images-to-png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting .jpg images to .png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759117/converting-jpg-images-to-png)

Comment: I referred that .. it is related to particular filename not a folder of images @codelearner

Comment: @SufiyanGhori..

Answer (score 0):

form a list of files with os.listdir() and iterate them with a for loop.

```
import os
image_path ='some_path/'
for img in os.listdir(image_path):
    input_image = Image.open(image_path+img).convert('RGB')
    input_image.save(image_path+img + ".png", "PNG")
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!