# Convert PNG to JPEG without Pillow

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

How can I convert a `PNG` file to `JPEG` without `Pillow` on `kivy` (`Python`)?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting .jpg images to .png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759117/converting-jpg-images-to-png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Kivy CoreImage](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html) to convert from png to jpg.

## Snippets

```
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage

img = CoreImage("linux.png")
img.save("linux.jpg")
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.10.1

<Demo>:
    img_png: img_png
    img_jpg: img_jpg

    RelativeLayout:
        Image:
            id: img_png
            pos_hint: {"left": 1, 'bottom': 1}
            size_hint: 0.5, 1
            allow_stretch: True

    RelativeLayout:
        Image:
            id: img_jpg
            pos_hint: {"right": 1, 'bottom': 1}
            size_hint: 0.5, 1
            allow_stretch: True
''')


class Demo(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Demo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        img = CoreImage("linux.png")
        img.save("linux.jpeg")
        self.img_png.source = "linux.png"
        self.img_jpg.source = "linux.jpeg"


runTouchApp(Demo())
```

## Output

[image: Converted image from png and jpeg]